# Rollupjs tree-shaking with typescript decorator modules

Tags: bundle, rollup, rollupjs

When I am using typescript decorators with modules in my script, rollupjs bundles entire modules instead of imported module.

**main.js**

```
import { outter } from './index.js';
let a = new outter();
```

**index.js**

```
export * from './display';
export * from './form';
```

**display.js**

```
export var outter = (function (_super) {
  console.log();
})();
```

**form.js**

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
function __() { this.constructor = d; }
d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};

var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};

export var err;
(function (err) {
   err[err["name"] = 0] = "name";
   err[err["error"] = 1] = "error";
})(err || (err = {}));

export var formV = (function (_super) {
  __extends(formV, _super);
  function formV(element, options) {
    _super.call(this, options, element);       
  }
  __decorate([
     Property(err.name)
  ], formV.prototype, "err", void 0);
  return formV;
}());
```

The formV module is not imported in the main.js file, but it also bundled with the output file.

**rollup.config.js**

```
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';

    export default {
        entry: 'main.js',    
        plugins: [
            nodeResolve({ jsnext: true })
        ],
        targets: [
            { dest: 'dist/rollup.js', format: 'cjs' },
            { dest: 'dist/rollup.es.js', format: 'es' },
            { dest: 'dist/rollup.amd.js', format: 'amd' }
        ],
        treeshake: true
    };
```

Comment: You'll need to share some more details of your config – what plugins are you using, etc? The code you've shared isn't actually valid JavaScript. If you can demonstrate the problem on rollupjs.org it will be much easier to solve.

Comment: @RichHarris: I have updated the codes and config settings

Comment: There's no obvious reason the sample code shouldn't bundle correctly. There must still be some important difference between the code/config here and the code/config that exhibits the problem. Can you share a minimal reproduction in a gist or repo? (i.e. git clone, npm install, npm run build to create a bundle that clearly shows the problem)

Comment: thanks for your reply and sorry for the inconvenience. I figured it out, when I am using decorate from typescript which modules are always bundled even I didn't import it. I have updated the code for your reference. From the example I didn't import formV module in main.js but it also bundled with the output file. I am very new to module bundling, so I don't know whether it is correct behavior or not.

Comment: Yeah, it's very difficult to know through static analysis whether or not it's safe to include that code – unfortunately that's one of the dangers of transpiling to JavaScript from another language